# Как нажать на кнопку в телеграм боте с помощью Pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Есть телеграм бот для скачивания аудио из Spotify (@spotify_down_bot)
Мне нужно скачать от туда аудио, для этого я отправляю боту ссылку на аудио и после чего бот отправляет мне сообщения с кнопками. Чтобы начать скачивание аудио надо нажать на кнопку Загрузить эту Песню!
Я пытался нажать на эту кнопку с помощью `client.request_callback_answer()`
Делал я это так
`Client.request_callback_answer(chat_id= 1130976121, message_id = message.message_id, callback_data = "d_mp3_slow 1T18xjRxt5m22ZOwMPMRhc")`
И ничего не происходит, скорее всего ошибка где-то в коде. Сам код:

```py
from pyrogram import Client
import config
import time

app = Client("cyberpunk", config.api_id, config.api_hash, config.phone_number)

@app.on_message()
def message(Client, message):
  if message.chat.username == "spotify_down_bot":
      print(message)

      log = open("log", "a")
      log.write(f"\n {message}")
      log.close()

      Client.request_callback_answer(
                   chat_id= 1130976121,
                   message_id = message.message_id,
                   callback_data = "d_mp3_slow 1T18xjRxt5m22ZOwMPMRhc"
      )
```

См информация из message https://pastebin.com/brQxFsxN

Answer (score -1):

```python
 Client.request_callback_answer(
                     chat_id= 1130976121,
                     message_id = message.message_id,
                     callback_data = message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[1][0]['callback_data']
)
```